# Do I need a transit visa when changing airlines and checking in luggage at Heathrow T2 and T3?

Tags: visas, transit, lhr

I'm travelling on a South African passport from Orlando USA to London Heathrow and landing at Terminal 3. After 8 hrs.
I do need to collect my luggage and check in my bags before boarding my next flight to Greece on a different airline departing from Terminal 2.
Currently I only have a US visa and a Shengen visa for Greece.

Comment: Per the linked question, it seems quite likely you do not, since you meet the requirement both from having  a US visa and from having a Schengen visa.

Comment: You say you need to collect your bags, do you mean you have two separate tickets (different PNRs)? If yes, then you will most probably not be allowed to board your flight from the US unless you have a UK visa, even you have an onward ticket and UK has an option for transit without visa for US visa holders. If you have a single ticket, for airside transit, no visa required with a US visa, for landside, UK allows it but airlines can be fussy, but most probably you will be allowed boarding as you are departing from the US.

Comment: I'm concerned that because I need to collect my baggage from airline 1 (Terminal 3) and then check baggage again at airline 2 (Terminal 2) that I may need to go through customs....which would require a transit visa.

Comment: Craig Winter: read @MJeffryes' comments. A person with a US visa or a Schengen visa is exempt from the requirement to have a UK transit visa.  But also heed Thomas Cruise's comment: you will likely have other problems if your flights are not on the same ticket.

Comment: Craig, you didn't tell how you know you need to collect baggage from airline. Do you have two separate tickets (PNRs)? There can be a single ticket on different airlines too. So it is not different airlines which is important but tickets. eg, Virgin offers single ticket with Aegean with interline transfer (thorough check in of bag). If you have two tickets, you need a UK visa.